# CollectionView inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I used `CollectionView` inside `TableViewCell`. All works fine and shown all as expected. But if I scrolled the `TableView` very fast, items (i used images in collectionView) from one collection replaced with items (images) from another collection and override it on View (on Debug mode in code al works fine, its just displaying of them).

**UITableView GetCell():**

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var item = _view.Items[indexPath.Row];
        var cell = (MyTableCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(“cell”);
        cell.TextLabelView.Text = item.Title;
        cell.YesButtonView.Hidden = item.IsCategory;
        cell.NoButtonView.Hidden = item.IsCategory;
        if (item.IsImagePoint)
        {
            cell.ImagesCollectionView.DataSource = new ItemsDataSource(item.Images, cell.ImagesCollectionView);
            cell.ImagesCollectionView.Delegate = new ItemsDelegate(item, _view);
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

**UICollectionView GetCell():**

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
            var cell = (ImageViewCell)_collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(new NSString(“ImageViewCell”), indexPath);
            var image = _images[indexPath.Row];
            var imagePath = image.ThumbnailPath;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath))
            {
                cell.ImagePath = imagePath;
            }
            return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Can you also add your code for `cellForItemAtIndexPath`? (both collection view and table view)

Comment: Share us your code and then we can help you better. This probably caused by reuse of cell.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Added code to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because of the reuse system of cells in `UITableView`. Do you set up properly your data when you configure the cell? Do you call `CollectionView`'s `reloadData()`?

**EDIT**: You should call it in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` where you configure your cell. This way, each time a cell is reused, you update its content.

**EDIT 2**: Just like I said try to add the collection view `reloadData()` when you set up your tableview cell. You also have to clean your datasource and delegate, because it's a reused cell so it may already have been used with another value.

```
 if (item.IsImagePoint)
    {
        cell.ImagesCollectionView.DataSource = new ItemsDataSource(item.Images, cell.ImagesCollectionView);
        cell.ImagesCollectionView.Delegate = new ItemsDelegate(item, _view);
    }
 else
    {
        cell.ImagesCollectionView.DataSource = null;
        cell.ImagesCollectionView.Delegate = null;
    }

 cell.ImagesCollectionView.ReloadData()

 return cell;
```

Comment: Just edited, But I don't know Xamarin so you should adapt. But the idea is that as you reuse a cell you must configure it each time (so also when your `item.IsImagePoint` is `false`) And you must tell the collection view to reload.

Comment: Thank you very much! U saved me. Awesome! Beer from me ;)
P.S. I've edited your answer according to Xamarin syntax (small changes).

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**
Add this in your custom `UITableViewCell` class.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

        collectionView.dataSource = nil
        collectionView.delegate = nil
        collectionView.reloadData()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
  }
```

Comment: My case tableview cell embeded collectionview with subclassed layout and this code works like charm.